# SQLRecoverableException while getting bytes from BLOB field

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle

I'm using Java and I'm reading data from a view that contains 6 fields, with the last one being a BLOB that contains PDF files.
To contextualize, the query I'm using is dynamic, so that through setting Table Name a Field names I can read anything just by passing parameters.

```
public class GenericDao {
    @Autowired
    EntityManager em;

    public List<?> findTableByDescriptionAndFields( String table, String fields) {
        String sql = "select "+ fields+" from " + table;
        System.out.println(sql);

        List<?> test = em.createNativeQuery(sql).getResultList();

        return test;
    }
}
```

This returns a List of Object[], each of which correspondes to the fields of the rows I'm reading.

```
        List<Object[]> lista = (List<Object[]>) genericDao.findTableByDescriptionAndFields("\"" +servizio.getDescription()+"\"", campi);
        List<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>> listOfObjects= new ArrayList<>() ;
        for(Object[] oggetto : lista) {
            LinkedHashMap<String, Object> mappa = new LinkedHashMap<>();
                for(int i = 0; i<servizio.getCampi().size(); i++) {
                      try {
                          if(oggetto[i] instanceof Blob) {
                                
                          Blob blob = (Blob) oggetto[i];
                          byte[] blobArray = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());


                      }
                        } catch(Exception e) {
                            ...some code
                        }
                    mappa.put(servizio.getCampi().get(i).getCwsLabelCampo(), oggetto[i]);
                }
                listOfObjects.add(mappa);
        }
```

I need to read the byte array to convert it in base64 and put it inside a json like I do with the rest of the data.
But when i try to launch this :
`byte[] blobArray = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());`
It gives me an SQLRecoverableException - Connection Closed. Why? Is there a way to solve this keeping the query adaptable to any view? Please Help.

Comment: In the code you posted any exception would be hidden by the empty `catch` block.  Is your actual code different?

Comment: No, I put that voluntarly cause I need the code to go on and expose the list of objects mapped for testing reasons.
Anyway I can read the Exception thrown through debug...
Can you please help? Don't worry about the exception being jumped...
Btw I updated the question to avoid anyone worrying about the exception :)

Comment: It appears you are using [Spring](https://spring.io/). Can you try using plain Java, i.e. **without** Spring? What Java version are you using? What Oracle version are you using? What JDBC driver are you using? From the error message that you posted in your question, my guess is that something in the Spring framework is closing the database connection. Hence my suggestion to see if you can succeed without using Spring.

Comment: I'm out of my depth here. Sorry.